# Validation success control

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, validation

Here is my code. My main problem is that var validationbool triggers success even if only one field of contact form is  valid and it does not care if the other ones are invalid. How can I create better control that var validationbool = true only when all elements are valid.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var validationBool = false;

    $('#register-form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                country: {
                    required: true
                },
                boat: {
                    required: true
                },
                lat: {
                    required: true
                },


                registration: {
                    required: true
                },

                file: {
                    required: true
                }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');

            validationBool = false;
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            validationBool = true;
        }
    });

    $('#register-form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(validationBool){

            var theData = {
                 name: $('#name').val(),
                 phone: $('#phone').val(),
                 email: $('#email').val(),
                 country: $('#country').val(),
                 lat: $('#lat').val(),
                 lng: $('#lng').val(),
                 boat: $('#boat').val(),
                 registration: $('#registration').val(),
                 file: $('#file').val()
            };

            $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
                url: "functions/enroll.php",
                type: 'post',
                data: theData,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    swal("Your request has been recieved!", "We will contact you for confirmation soon", "success");
                    document.getElementById('name').value='',
                    document.getElementById('phone').value='',
                    document.getElementById('email').value='',
                    document.getElementById('country').value='',
                    document.getElementById('lat').value='',
                    document.getElementById('lng').value='',
                    document.getElementById('boat').value='',
                    document.getElementById('file').value='',
                    document.getElementById('registration').value='';

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the ``valid()`` method to check if the form is valid .

Comment: I just need to create better control in section 

        success: function (element) {
            element.text('').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            validationBool = true;
        }

So it passes true only when all fields are valid and not only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `.valid()` mehthod.

This would be printed like

`var myForm = $("#register-form");
 myForm.validate();`

then, instead of using the "validationBool" variable, use

`if (myForm.valid())`

to check if the form is validated - this will check all fields.

Comment: Because I'm lazy - can you post your HTML as well for me so I can jsfiddle the whole thing in practice or is it sensitive?

Comment: I've had to take a few things out (obviously the fancy alerts and stuff) - But I've managed to give you a rough idea on how to implement the .validate() method into your code. http://jsfiddle.net/fqoj1j2t/3/ - I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry! Uploaded the wrong link/version.. use this one http://jsfiddle.net/fqoj1j2t/7/

Comment: Cool, ill try it. But what to do with all this code that you commented out, I mean how to send AJAX request and reset fields without it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I thought will work for you with `validate()`:

[Note: This is just an example I used and you can use the similar approach - You don't have to explicitly use any **boolean** variable for knowing whether you can submit.

Do note, I used:

1. [Invalidate Handler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#invalidhandler) - Callback for custom code when an invalid form is submitted. Called with an event object as the first argument, and the validator as the second.
2. [Submit Handler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) -  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

*Html code:*

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
            <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
            <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
            <input id="curl" type="url" name="url" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
            <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

*JS code:*

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 3,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10
        },
        country: {
            required: true
        },
        boat: {
            required: true
        },
        lat: {
            required: true
        },
        registration: {
            required: true
        },
        file: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        /*Here you will get your errors
            if (errors) {
              var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
              $("div.error span").html(message);
              $("div.error").show();
        } else {
          $("div.error").hide();
        }*/
        alert(errors);
    },
    submitHandler: function (element) {
        //Handler for submit action
        //$(form).ajaxSubmit();
        alert("submit");
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle Link here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nagtan3/gkypk68L/)

Comment: Tnx Ill try it and let you know.